# add/publish new field data for existing channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, custom-fields

I have and existing channel with existing entries. I added a new custom field, a radio button group, with options YES/NO, with the default option being YES.

The field is now available in the edit entry form but it has no value set until I click an option (YES) and then save the form.

Is there a way to set/publish the default value for all existing entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to run a query on the database to set the past entries' values for this new field:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_XX = 'YES' WHERE field_id_XX == '' AND channel_id = X;
```

Just replace `XX` with the correct `field_id` and `X` with the correct `channel_id`.

And, as with anytime you run a write query on the database, back it up first!

Comment: I had to change the double '==' to a single '=' and then it worked.